# oracle query to group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query as follows:

```
select c.case_id, c.last_name, c.first_name, lkp_alt.descr alt, lkp_cs.descr caseStatus, u.last_name || ','|| u.first_name createdBy,
             ul.last_name ||','||ul.first_name lastModifiedBy, c.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
             from cases c left outer join lkP_alt_show_cause_authority lkp_alt
             on c.ATL_SHOW_CAUSE_AUTHORITY = lkp_alt.id
             left outer join cases_case_status cStatus
             on c.case_id = cStatus.case_id
             left outer join lkp_case_status lkp_cs
             on cStatus.case_status_id = lkp_cs.id
             left outer join users u
             on c.created_by = u.id
             left outer join users ul
             on c.LAST_MODIFIED_BY = ul.id;
```

Output looks like below,

```
case_id last_name first_name    alt     caseStatus  createdBy   lastModifiedBy  
1       lName   fName           MCCDC   Active      aaa         aaa             
1       lName   fName           MCCDC   Closed      aaa         aaa             
100     lName1  fName1          MCCDC   Closed      aaa         ,               
100     lName1  fName1          MCCDC   Active      aaa         ,               
16023   lName2  fName2          MCCDC   Closed      aaa         ,               
16023   lName2  fName2          MCCDC   Active      aaa         ,               
16025   lName3  fName3          MCCDC   Active      aaa         ,               
16025   lName3  fName3          MCCDC   Closed      aaa         ,               
16027   lName4  fName4          II MEF  JPAS        aaa         ,   
16027   lName4  fName4          II MEF  IGMC        aaa         ,   
16027   lName4  fName4          II MEF  Active      aaa         ,   
16029   lName5  fName5          MCCDC   Closed      aaa         ,               
16029   lName5  fName5          MCCDC   Active      aaa         ,               
16031   lName6  fName6          MCCDC   Closed      aaa         ,               
16031   lName6  fName6          MCCDC   Active      aaa         ,
```

From above caseStatus for each caseId has a ManytoOne relationship. I want the display as follows where caseStatus is seperated by commas if they are more than 1.

```
case_id last_name first_name    alt     caseStatus          createdBy   lastModifiedBy  
1       lName   fName           MCCDC   Active, Closed      aaa         aaa             
100     lName1  fName1          MCCDC   Active, Closed      aaa         ,               
16023   lName2  fName2          MCCDC   Active, Closed      aaa         ,               
16025   lName3  fName3          MCCDC   Active, Closed      aaa         ,               
16027   lName4  fName4          II MEF  JPAS, IGMC, Active  aaa         ,   
16029   lName5  fName5          MCCDC   Active, Closed      aaa         ,               
16031   lName6  fName6          MCCDC   Active, Closed      aaa         ,
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Unless you're using a rather old version, you probably just want to use the `listagg` function.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Comment: listagg with a group by